# Capture output of command which contains quotes and env vars

Tags: bash

I know I can capture the output of a bash command like this:

```
OUTPUT="$(ls -1)"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

But my command itself contains a lot of quotes:

```
OUTPUT="$(curl -v -u ${USER}:${PASSWD} -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"xxx": true,
"xxx2": "date",
...
}' https://${ENV}/${ROOT}/api/try)"
```

but this returns an empty string:

```
echo $OUTPUT
```

How can I capture the output of this command?

Comment: Returning an empty string has nothing to do with the quotes. Perhaps the `curl` query you have would return empty even if you run in the commandline without capturing the output

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function with your complex command:

```
cmdfn() {
   curl -v -u ${USER}:${PASSWD} -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
   "xxx": true,
   "xxx2": "date",
   ...
   }' https://${ENV}/${ROOT}/api/try
}
```

Then call it in command substitution as:

```
output="$(cmdfn)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, either escape the quotes inside the string with \", or use single quotes, i.e.

```
% BLA="bla \"a\""
% echo $BLA
bla "a"
% BLA='bla "a"'
% echo $BLA
bla "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash handles nested quotes and parentheses very well. This is not the case

```
OUTPUT="$(curl -v -u ${USER}:${PASSWD} -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"xxx": true,
"xxx2": "date",
...
}' https://${ENV}/${ROOT}/api/try)"
```

It's possible that `curl` itself is not echoing anything.